# SUM for Multiple Table and Child Table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sum, multiple-tables

I need to create JOIN syntax for this query in MySQL :

```
SELECT 
    TblSupplier.SupplierName AS SupplierName, 
    (SUM(TblBuy.TotalBuy) - SUM(TblReturn.TotalReturn)) AS Total 
    (SUM(TblPayment.TotalPaymentToday) - SUM(TblReturnItem.TotalReturnToday)) AS TotalPayment, 
    ((SUM(TblBuy.TotalBuy) - SUM(TblReturn.TotalReturn)) - (SUM(TblPayment.TotalPaymentToday) - SUM(TblReturnItem.TotalReturnToday))) AS Balance 
FROM ... 
GROUP BY TblSupplier.ID
```

but I don't know how to do it...

[This is my ER Diagram](http://postimg.org/image/628twkeel/)

Example for my question:

> INSERT INTO TableSupplier (ID, SupplierName) VALUES (1, 'Company A'), (2, 'Company B');
>
> INSERT INTO TableBuy (ID, SupplierID, TotalBuy) VALUES
>   (1, 1, 100),
>   (2, 1, 200),
>   (3, 2, 50),
>   (4, 2, 100),
>   (5, 2, 50);
>
> INSERT INTO TablePayment (ID, BuyID, TotalPaymentToday) VALUES
>   (1, 1, 50),
>   (2, 3, 50);
>
> INSERT INTO TableReturn (ID, SupplierID, TotalReturn) VALUES
>   (1, 1, 20),
>   (2, 2, 30),
>   (3, 2, 10);
>
> INSERT INTO TableReturnItem (ID, ReturnID, TotalReturnToday) VALUES
>   (1, 1, 10),
>   (2, 2, 30);

I follow this example, I got this result:

> mysql> select 
>      -> ts.SupplierName AS  SupplierName, 
>      -> (SUM(tb.TotalBuy) - SUM(tr.TotalReturn)) AS Total, 
>      -> (SUM(tp.TotalPaymentToday) - SUM(tri.TotalReturnToday)) AS TotalPayment, 
>      -> ((SUM(tb.TotalBuy) - SUM(tr.TotalReturn)) - 
>      -> (SUM(tp.TotalPaymentToday) -     SUM(tri.TotalReturnToday))) AS Balance 
>      -> from tablesupplier ts 
>      -> inner join tablebuy tb on ts.id=tb.id 
>      -> inner join tablereturn tr on ts.id=tr.id 
>      -> inner join tablepayment tp on ts.id=tp.id 
>      -> inner join tablereturnitem tri on ts.id=tri.id 
>      -> group by ts.id; 
>   SupplierName | Total | TotalPayment | Balance 
>   ------------------------------------------------- 
>   Company A | 80 | 40 | 40 
>   Company B | 170 | 20 | 150

The result I want is:

> SupplierName | Total | TotalPayment | Balance 
>   ------------------------------------------------- 
>   Company A | 280 | 40 | 240 
>   Company B | 160 | 20 | 140

Comment: and that doesnt work?

Comment: yes, I don't know how to create join syntax for that query, value (result) will be duplicate

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: jtseng, see again my question for example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select 
ts.SupplierName AS SupplierName, 
(SUM(tb.TotalBuy) - SUM(tr.TotalReturn)) AS Total 
(SUM(tp.TotalPaymentToday) - SUM(tri.TotalReturnToday)) AS TotalPayment, 
((SUM(tb.TotalBuy) - SUM(tr.TotalReturn)) - 
(SUM(tp.TotalPaymentToday) -     SUM(tri.TotalReturnToday))) AS Balance 
from tablesupplier ts
inner join tablebuy tb on ts.id=tb.supplierid
inner join tablereturn tr on ts.id=tr.supplierid
inner join tablepayment tp on tb.id=tp.buyid
inner join tablereturnitem tri on tr.id=tri.returnid
group by ts.id
```

Comment: hello daniel, thank's for answering my question, but the answer still wrong, see my last edit in my question for explanation